# sharing default parameter value in interface class and derived classes in c++

Tags: c++

I want to use float value (defaultColour) as a default parameter, in both interface class and Derived class. So how should I define that float  defaultColour[] .?

```
//Interface class
static float defaultColour[]={0,0,0,0}; //This become error

class Interface{
    virtual void print_color(float *color = defaultColour)=0;
}

//Use Interface  Derived.h 
class Derived : public Interface{
    void print_color(float *a = defaultColour);
}

//Derived.cpp 
void Derived :: print_color(float *a){
    //some code using color a[]
}
```

Comment: Your problem is with inheritance, it's with using the array as a default value. The wording of your question is misleading. Also, your code sample violates the ODR, so it will raise errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: @StoryTeller How come ? The array should decay with no issue.

Comment: @Quentin -- Using a non `constexpr` as a default argument is news to me...

Comment: you also forget a semi-colon ; after the class defenition

Comment: @StoryTeller [works dandy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab20787c7bb115ed), and in old C++03 too :)

Comment: @StoryTeller How can I solve this with constexpr?.Are there any othe way with inheritance?

Comment: As Quentin pointed out, I was wrong about *that*. And I do apologize. The other problems with you example still stand however.

Comment: @StoryTeller works dandy example is with in class initialization. It  is no conflict. but here is the Sharing with both classes.

Answer (score 2):

The default array value should not actually be a problem.  With the syntax errors in your examples sorted out, the following example [works fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fed3d2a2bd19a92):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

static float default_array[] = { 42.0f, 13.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f };

struct Interface
{
  virtual void foo(float *a = default_array) = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Interface
{
  void foo(float *a);
};

// Silly contrived example: output array values until a 0 is hit.  You
// better make sure there actually is a 0 at the end.
void Derived::foo(float *a)
{
  while (*a != 0.0f)
  {
    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    ++a;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Interface> i(new Derived);
  std::cout << "i->foo():" << std::endl;
  i->foo();
  float other_array[] = { 1.0f, -2.0f, 3.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f };
  std::cout << "i->foo(other_array):" << std::endl;
  i->foo(other_array);
}
```

Note, however, that defining `default_array` in the header will violate the One Definition Rule if multiple compilation units include that header.  To avoid that, you will have to use @MartinBonner's solution and make the array a static member variable.

If you know that you will call `foo()` *only through a pointer to `Interface`*, then you do not need to re-specify the default value in `Derived::foo`'s declaration.  However, if you also expect to do something like this:

```
  Derived der;
  der.foo();
```

Then you will run into a problem because `Derived::foo()` does not actually exist.  GCC will complain:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:37:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::foo()’
       der.foo();
               ^
test.cpp:37:15: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:18:10: note: virtual void Derived::foo(float*)
     void Derived::foo(float *a)
          ^
test.cpp:18:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

A somewhat generic workaround in this case could be to add the following inline function declaration to `Derived`:

```
inline void foo() { static_cast<Interface*>(this)->foo(); }
```

Comment: Why not just `void foo(float *a = default_array) override;`  in `Derived`?

Comment: Are you convinced this doesn't violate the ODR?  If you include `interface.h` in multiple translation units, each definition of `Interface` will have a subtly different declaration of `print_color` - specifically the default argument will be a different pointer.

Comment: @MartinBonner re your first question: Yes, you could just do that, but I wanted to be a bit more DRY and avoid the duplication.

Comment: Oh. As for your second question, you're absolutely right about the ODR. The moment you move the definition of `default_array` out of the header, you cannot use it as a default parameter anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Make `defaultColour` a const static public member of Interface.

Interface.h

```
    class Interface{
    public:
        static float defaultColour[colourSize]; // You have got a const for the
                                                // array size somewhere,
                                                // haven't you?

        virtual void print_color(float *color = defaultColour)=0;

    }; // Need trailing ; here
```

Derived.h

```
    class Derived : public Interface {  // Need to derive from Interface.
    public:
        void print_color(float *a = defaultColour); // Just declare function here.
    };
```

Derived.cpp

```
    void Derived::print_color(float *a){  // define function here.
            //some code using color a[]
    }
```

Interface.cpp (this may be a new file)

```
    float Interface::defaultColour[] = {255,255,255,150};
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out, that re-specifying the default value for a derived class is pointless. The base's will always be used in a polymorphic context.

Comment: Yes. this is ok. but if I want to set defaultColour={255,255,255,150}    then what should I do? (Interface.cpp is not posible)

Comment: @StoryTeller:  On the contrary.  If you have specified a default value for a base class, you should always specify the *same default* for a derived class.  That way `pInterface->print_color();` and `pDerived->print_color();` will behave the same.

Comment: @mai: I have update the answer to initialize `defaultColour` to non-zero.  You will have to explain why Interface.cpp is not possible.

Comment: Incidentally, the static should be called `defaultColor` to be consistent with `print_color` and all the other API calls which misspell "colour" (you'd never guess I was English, would you?)

Comment: @MartinBonner, `pDerived->print_color();` is not a polymorphic context. Only `pInterface->print_color();` is.

Comment: @StoryTeller: a)  `pDerived->print_color();` *is* a polymorphic context - there might be a class derived from `Derived`, and is its `print_color` that will be invoked; b) Even if it was `derived.print_color()` (with `derived` an object of `Derived` type), I would still argue it should behave the same as `pInterface->print_color()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK.Thanks every one. I solved with this way. Are there any bad rules?

```
//Interface class
    class Interface{
        public:
        virtual void print_color(const float *color = defaultColour)=0;
        protected:
        static const float defaultColour[4];
    }

    //Use Interface  Derived.h 
    class Derived : public Interface{
        void print_color(const float *a = defaultColour);
    }

    //Derived.cpp 
    Interface::defaultColour[]={0,0,0,0};
    void Derived :: print_color(const float *a){
            //some code using color a[]
    }
```